# Matrix over a ring representation

Tags: matrix-equations

Let $R$ is a ring, $M$ is a $n \times n$ matrix over the ring $R$ 
(i.e. $M \in M_n(R)$). I need to prove that $\exists M' \in M_n(R)$ such that 
$M' M = \det M \cdot E$, where $E \in M_n(R)$ is the identity matrix.

My proof is the following:

1. If $\det M = 0$ then we can assume $M' = 0$
2. If $\det M \ne 0$ then there exists $M^{-1}$ and therefore $M' = \det M \cdot M^{-1}$ will work.

Are there any errors in the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ring $R$ should be commutative in order for the determinant to be defined.

However, if a matrix has nonzero determinant, it may not be invertible. Consider, for instance, $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
in $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$, which has nonzero determinant but is not invertible.

The result is true nonetheless. Hint: consider the [*adjugate matrix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of $M$.

> You can consider the field $\mathbb{Q}(x_{ij})$ (over $n^2$ indeterminates) where the inverse of the formal matrix $[x_{ij}]$ exists, so you can prove there the theorem that $(\operatorname{adj}M)M=(\det M)E$ and note that the coefficients $\operatorname{adj}M$ are just polynomials in $x_{ij}$, so you can perform substitutions with the actual coefficients you have over the ring $R$.

Comment: I've got it. Thank you a lot. My proof is valid only if $R$ is a field. But in general case it is not correct.

Comment: @IvanMurashko That's right. I added a spoiler.